# Pure functions in React with state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

I've been reading more about functional programming and how React components are in essence all pure functions, but I'm confused as to how functions within React components can be considered pure if you are using state from outside of them? Is it just a given that functions inside of a React component will not be pure?

I've created a contrived example, but I can't recall ever seeing an example where what I have done in the `handleMinusClick` function is suggested. Is what I am doing in `handlePlusClick` considered to be bad practice if I were to be adhering to the functional programming paradigm?

```
// Pure
const Counter = ({ value }) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(value);

  // Pure?
  const handleMinusClick = counter => {
    return counter - 1;
  };

  // Unpure?
  const handlePlusClick = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(handleMinusClick(counter))}>
        Minus
      </button>
      {counter}
      <button onClick={handlePlusClick}>Plus</button>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Counter value={123} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-feather-ggdld

Comment: A pure function uses only variables passed as arguments. It should always give the same output if it is given the same input. You are using counter, but it is not a parameter, hence why the second function is impure. When you call it, you never know what to expect, whereas with the first, you always know that whatever you've just given it will give back that number - 1

Comment: "Finally, if you’re a functional programming purist and feel uneasy about React relying on mutable state as an implementation detail, you might find it satisfactory that handling Hooks could be implemented in a pure way using algebraic effects (if JavaScript supported them). And of course React has always relied on mutable state internally — precisely so that you don’t have to." — Dan Abramov https://dev.to/dan_abramov/making-sense-of-react-hooks-2eib

Comment: More from Abramov on algebraic effects: https://overreacted.io/algebraic-effects-for-the-rest-of-us/